# need baseurl in config.js file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, config, base-url

In my config.js file (pasted below), I need to get the base url but the php base url script I have used doesn't work. Any suggestions on what I can use to replace the php base url below ?

```
BOBBIEEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.fileopener = '<?php echo $this->baseUrl;?>files/browse.php?opener=bobbieeditor&type=files';
};
```

Comment: Save as a PHP file, and use HTACCESS as a `RewriteRule` for `config.js` to `config.php` ?

Answer (score 2):

Can you put the value of $this->baseUrl; in metas for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="data-base-url" content="<?php echo $this->baseUrl;?>" />
```

and get it with JS:

```
var base_url = document.querySelectorAll('head > meta[name="data-base-url"]');
var base_content = base_url[0].getAttribute('content');
```